# PHP preg_replace from beginning of word

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to run a preg_replace or str_replace to wrap URLs in `<a>` tags - this is an example of what I have:

```
$string = "this is my website: mysite.com and this is my email: name@mysite.com";

$link = 'mysite.com';

echo str_replace($link, '<a>'.$link.'</a>', $string);
```

This is the result:

```
this is my website: <a>mysite.com</a> and this is my email: name@<a>mysite.com</a>
```

Obviously I don't want to wrap the end of the email address, is there a way that I can run the replace only from the beginning of words and ignore any results which are in the middle of other characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo preg_replace_all('/\\s(mysite\\.com)/i','<a>$1</a>',$string);
```

You can find out more about regular expression [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php).

Comment: The word boundary sees `@` as a word boundary and ends up with the same result. Also, is `g` a valid pattern modifier in PCRE?

Comment: Thank you for these, I literally just put this together and it seems to do the job:

$p = "/(^|([\s]+))(mysite.com)/";
$r = '$2<a>$3</a>';

echo preg_replace($p, $r, $string);

Think its best to give up when its late sometimes...

Comment: @Warren: why writting something like `[\s]+`, it has no sense! 1) why putting a shorthand character class inside square brackets? 2) why do you need to check more than one space character *(with the `+` quantifier)*? A trick to make all shorter is to use a negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` and a negative lookahead `(?!...)` that are only checks and are not parts of the match result: `$p = '/(?<!\S)mysite\.com(?!\S)/'; $r = '<a>$0</a>';` In other words, this means: *not preceded and not followed by a non-space character* (this takes account cases of end and start of the string).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for this! This is a much better solution to the problem and work exactly how I needed it to.